# Maximising $Tr(PAPB)$ for orthogonal projection matrix $P$ and symmetric $A,B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-optimization, trace

I want to find a vector $u$ that maximises $Tr(PAPB)$ where $P$ is an orthogonal projection over $u$, for symmetric $A,B$. Does this problem have a closed form solution?

Thanks

Comment: If $U$ is orthogonal, then isn't $UU^\top$ the identity matrix?

Comment: Sorry, it should be $U^TU$...fixed.

Comment: That's still the identity matrix.

Comment: Really sorry...please see the updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\|u\|=1$, you can write $P=uu^T$, then
\begin{align*}
\text{Tr}(PAPB) &= \text{Tr}(uu^TAuu^TB)\\
&= \text{Tr}(u^TAuu^TBu)\\
&= u^TAuu^TBu
\end{align*}
since it is a scalar. So this is the expression that you want to maximize.

I do not know a closed form expression for that, however so bounds can be given, a trivial one is that since $u$ has unit norm, we have $u^T A u\in[\lambda_1(A),\lambda_n(A)]$ and $u^T B u\in[\lambda_1(B),\lambda_n(B)]$, where $\lambda_k(X)$ is the $k$'th smalest eigenvalue of $X$. If we take $u$ to be the eigenvector associated to the $k$'th eigenvalue of $A$, we obtain that $u^T A u=\lambda_k(A)$ and so $$u^T A u u^T B u = \lambda_k(A)u^T B u\geq \min(\lambda_k(A)\lambda_n(B),\lambda_k(A)\lambda_1(B))$$This means that
\begin{align*}
\max_u u^TAuu^TBu &\geq \max_k \min(\lambda_k(A)\lambda_n(B),\lambda_k(A)\lambda_1(B))\\
&=\max(\min(\lambda_1(A)\lambda_n(B),\lambda_1(A)\lambda_1(B)),\min(\lambda_n(A)\lambda_n(B),\lambda_n(A)\lambda_1(B)))
\end{align*}
You can also inverse the role of $A$ and $B$ to get that
\begin{align*}
\max_u u^TAuu^TBu &\geq \max(\min(\lambda_1(B)\lambda_n(A),\lambda_1(B)\lambda_1(A)),\min(\lambda_n(B)\lambda_n(A),\lambda_n(B)\lambda_1(A)))
\end{align*}

We can find $A$ and $B$ such that this is tight, but the value can also go up to $\max(\lambda_1(A)\lambda_1(B), \lambda_n(A)\lambda_n(B))$ when the same eigenvector achieves the largest (lowest if they are negative) eigenvalues. So in general any value between those two is achievable by some matrices $A$ and $B$.

---

If $A$ and $B$ are both PSD, then all eigen values are positive and
\begin{align*}
&\max(\min(\lambda_1(A)\lambda_n(B),\lambda_1(A)\lambda_1(B)),\min(\lambda_n(A)\lambda_n(B),\lambda_n(A)\lambda_1(B)))\\
=&\max(\lambda_1(A)\lambda_n(B),\lambda_1(A)\lambda_1(B))\\
=&\lambda_1(A)\lambda_n(B)
\end{align*}
and similarly we are bounded by $\lambda_n(A)\lambda_1(B)$.

Comment: @PQuin, in your first inequality you are assuming that $\lambda_1(A)\geq 0$, no?

Comment: Thank you for the catch, actually if it is negative then the best bound we can get is by multiplying it by $\lambda_1(B)$ instead, hence I changed the lower bound to the max of $\lambda_i(A)\lambda_j(A)$ for $\{ j,n \}\subseteq \{ 1,n \}$.

Comment: Thanks! Can this bound become tighter if $A$, $B$ are also PSD?

Comment: Actually, it is wrong, let me fix it and add a comment about PSD.